# Accessing multi-index value in pivot table using pandas in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample transaction dataframe as below:
[image]

I wanted to get the sum of quantity sold for each item grouped by year.
So, I wrote the below line for it:

```
table=pd.pivot_table(df,index=["ITEMNUMBER"],columns=["YEAR"],values=["QTY_SOLD"],aggfunc=np.sum)
```

And my output comes like this:

```
         QTY_SOLD                    
YEAR           2016 2017 2018 2019 2020
ITEMNUMBER                             
A               3.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
B               0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  5.0
C               0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

How can I access each year's data by iterating over the itemnumber column?
I tried reindexing but that gives me the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `[]` for avoid `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
table=pd.pivot_table(df,index="ITEMNUMBER",columns="YEAR",values="QTY_SOLD",aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Possible solution with your output is:

```
table=pd.pivot_table(df,index=["ITEMNUMBER"],columns=["YEAR"],values=["QTY_SOLD"],aggfunc=np.sum).droplevel(0, axis=1)
```

For select by index and column use:

```
for idx in table.index:
    for col in table.columns:
        print (table.loc[idx, col])
        3.0
        0.0
        0.0
        0.0
        0.0
        0.0
        0.0
        0.0
        0.0
        5.0
        0.0
        0.0
        0.0
        0.0
        0.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. But, my original question was "How can I access each year's data by iterating over the itemnumber column?"

Comment: @KhyatiAgrawal - Not sure if understand, do you need edited answer?

Comment: I want to get the values for each year and each Item by using some loop. I am unable to get that.

Comment: @KhyatiAgrawal - For me working wery well, not some typo?